# In a headline written with initial capitals, should "outside" be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, style-manuals, headline-case

I'm writing a headline for an article ending with "outside the organization."  According to our style book, we capitalize on headline.  Should "outside" be capitalized in this context?

Comment: I see no reason why it shouldn't but it would help if you could give us the whole headline.

Answer (score 1):

Capitalization is more of a style choice per-se. However, AP style dictates that you should capitalize the first letter of each word, excluding articles, such as the, coordinating conjunctions, and prepositions that are three letters or fewer. Therefore, outside should be capitalized.